# Icon when added project to tfs

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm new to TFS, I added my solution to the TFS, it looks like:

[image]

but when I look at other projects, the other projects looks like:

[image]

with this small icon, why? I mean I need also this icon?If so how to get it?

Comment: That icon indicates a branch. If you want a branch, right click the top level folder->Branching and Merging, it's one of the options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/repos/tfvc/use-branches-isolate-risk-team-foundation-version-control?view=vsts) symbol. You can use branches to isolate risk and accomplish the following goals:

- Manage concurrent work by multiple teams on the same codebase
- Isolate risks that are introduced by different sets of changes to the
  codebase
- Take snapshots and then support subsequent isolated changes (for
  example, to create a release branch)

Check the following link for more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/repos/tfvc/branch-folders-files?view=vsts